# Simulating square to sine wave conversion via LC circuit results in 200-fold amplification

Tags: capacitor, filter, inductor, sine, square

After watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmkzmHQfR20&t=309s) I decided to simulate the following circuit in PSpice:

[image]

Time domain simulation with general settings, TSTOP of 100 ms and maximum step size of 1 μs yielded the following sine and Fourier graphs:

[image]

[image]

By rearranging the formula:

$$f=1/2\pi\sqrt{LC}$$

we get:

$$LC=(1/2\pi f)^2$$

If we let L = C and do the math, we get impedance and capacitance of ~7.95775 µH and µF respectively.

Where does the increased voltage come from?

How does the voltage get negative?

Interestingly, if we change inductance to 796 μH and capacitance to 79.6 nF hence increasing the former by a factor of 100 and decreasing the latter by the same factor leaving the product unchanged, we get a smaller, +35.5 to -30.5 sine wave, without the guitar shape at the start. The original circuit's wave oscillates between +980.4 and -975.3. I'm guessing the voltage doesn't really change, since the bias voltage of +5 V stays the same. But I don't really understand what is happening and why.

Also, the Fourier graphs in both instances start with virtually the same drop:

[image]

Unclear why.

And more importantly, how do we preserve the amplitude of +5 - 0 V?

**UPDATE**

As per Andy's suggestion I tried maximizing the difference between L and C and set them to 79.6 mH and 796 pF respectively which yielded the following graphs (notice the spike at 60 kHz):

[image]

[image]

Why does that happen despite the LC product remaining the same? Are other formulas at work, or are we reaching the edge of the formula's function domain?

Comment: You might want to reality-check the source current. Would your source actually have zero impedance?

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm not sure how to add the impedance to the power source. Or resistance to inductor for that matter.

Comment: Putting a resistor in series with them, perhaps?

Comment: You're simulating ideal components. The simulation is correct. If you actually assemble this circuit, it will perform differently - the amplitude will be much lower. *I'm not sure how to add [...] resistance to inductor* - you're adding series resistance. ESR means equivalent series resistance. So just add a series resistor with the desired resistance in series with the coil. A small 7mH coil will have say between 0.1k to 1kohm resistance, just to have a ballpark.

Answer (score 3):

> *Where does the increased voltage come from?*

The filter you have designed has a Q factor of exactly 1000. This means that at the natural resonant frequency (19.9934 kHz) the circuit amplifies voltage by a factor of 1000. I note you are using a 20 kHz signal (PER = 50 us) and this is really quite close to the natural resonant frequency.

> *How does the voltage get negative?*

The output (1000 times bigger than the input) is superimposed on the average level of the input. Given that the input's average level is 2.5 volts, it will generate large positive and negative amplitudes.

The [Tacoma bridge](https://www.google.com/search?client=avast-a-1&q=tacoma+bridge+resonance&oq=tahoma+bridge&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqBggDEAAYQDIGCAAQRRg5MgYIARAAGEAyBggCEAAYQDIGCAMQABhAMgYIBBAAGEAyBggFEAAYQDIGCAYQABhAMgYIBxAAGEDSAQk5NDQ2ajBqMTWoAgCwAgA&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:6c8ea2ac,vid:XggxeuFDaDU,st:0) had a problem with under-damped resonance and. this is what you have.

Comment: I'll read up on Q factor. Does it have a simple formula? Also, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I know it does look like it but, it has the Q factor of a parallel RLC circuit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor#RLC_circuits. You can lower the Q-factor by making L much larger and C much smaller. So, if you made C = 79.60 nF and L = 796 uH it would have a much lower Q factor. If you them made R = 100 ohm, it would have a Q of unity.

Comment: When I set C and L to those values the amplitude still jumps to +35 ~ -30. When I do C = 7.96 nF and L = 7960 uH voltage goes +5.8 ~ -0.8 but on Fourier graph the spike at 20 kHz decreases to 3 V and the spike at 60 kHz becomes noticeable 100 mV

Comment: When I go even Further and set L = 79.6mH and C = 796pF, graph takes a weird shape (see updated post).

Comment: Nothing weird about that at all. The extra spectral points are just because your transient response covers the initial transient situation and, that means that the Fourier analysis will show oddities. No point doing Fourier here until it's working how you want it to and the sinewave "looks" good then, analyse complete stable cycles to get Fourier results that are more realistic. @beardeadclown

Answer (score 2):

You have some simulation artifacts in there (the undulating modulation is not physical). Try a minimum step of 100ns. Try an even shorter time than that and see if there is any difference, don't just believe me.

You're exciting a resonance and this is more-or-less what would happen in reality if you had parts like these (if they could even exist). I don't know about the default in your version of Pspice, but in LTspice the inductor has a hidden default series resistance of 0.001Ω. That may not sound like much, but it will make difference in a circuit like this. Try 1mΩ vs. 1uΩ vs. 1Ω. Maybe look at datasheets for real inductors and see what resistances are available.

Note that the circuit is supplying **thousands of watts** to the load resistor, so the peak currents from the "signal" source are **more than 1000A peak**. That's not going to happen with your benchtop signal generator. Try a 50Ω signal generator source impedance and see what happens.

Comment: There are no resistance/impedance parameters, but there is BiasPower, will that do?

Comment: Will that do for what?  You can simulate the 50Ω source impedance by adding a resistor in series with the ideal signal source.

Comment: Oh, I tried that and it did nothing.

Comment: It should have a rather profound effect.